# How to create a jump code from boolean expression?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I want to create a jump code statement for the following boolean expression how can I do that? Can someone give me an example which helps me to solve further problems related to the same?

```
if(a>b) and (c>d) or(e!=f)
then -clause
else
else-clause
```

Comment: I have posted the same question in cs but I got a strange recommendation which is here https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/102601/how-to-create-a-jump-code-for-the-following-boolean-expression?noredirect=1#comment219064_102601

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: It is not specific to any specifics programming language. Anything will do One reference I got from internet http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno//CS447/Lectures/IntermediateCode.html/node4.html

Comment: The answers depends on the specific programming language you're using. Different languages express control flow differently.

Comment: Any programming language will work this question is not intended to a single programming language

Comment: On the web page you provided as an example, their jump code is just `goto`.

Comment: That's fine I am looking for a home work help product engineer still not finished my grad school :)

Comment: If this is homework, you need to disclose any outside assistance.

Comment: I have added one resource the answer is somthing like that just goto or somthing like that.